# mustache using .get(key) function for each object

Tags: javascript, templates, mustache

I have some JSON models that look like:

`{entries: [Entry{get: function}, Entry{get: function}]}`

I then want to iterate over each entry and use the get function to get attributes. The part I am having trouble with is calling the get function. I have tried:

```
{{#entries}}
    <tr>
        <td class="time-col">{{get('eventTime')}}</td>
        <td class="description-col">{{{this.get('Description')}}}</td>
    </tr>
{{/entries}}
```

as well as a few other things and can't seem to figure it out. They mention functions in the docs, but it is only functions used to render other things.

Any tips would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Mustache does not support `{{get('eventTime')}}` syntax. Mustache tags must contain identifiers like `name`, or compound expressions like `foo.bar`, and nothing like function calls of string literals.

I advise you to "prepare your ViewModel object", which means give to the Mustache engine a carefully crafted Javascript object with keys that match template identifiers, and not the javascript object you describe.

Instead of `Entry{get: function}`, provide `{eventTime:..., Description:...}`.

Yes, this preparation phase is a chore, which plagues all Mustache implementations that strictly adhere to the specification.

Comment: I mean, some other implementations allow to execute a function when a key could not be resolved (for example: https://github.com/groue/GRMustache/blob/master/Guides/view_model.md#default-values ). You could then write `{{eventTime}}` and have your catch-all function return `get('eventTime')`. You may consider open a feature request in the repository of your Mustache implementation.